# writing to /proc/net/xt_recent/ in python

Tags: python-3.x

What is the best way to write to `/proc` filesystem from python3, specifically writing to `/proc/net/xt_recent/`

In shell, I would do:

```
echo +10.10.10.10 > /proc/net/xt_recent/BLOCKED
```

Which would add IP addresds to the list used by the iptables recent module

How can I do this in `python3` ?

Comment: You could just use `os.system("echo +10.10.10.10 > /proc/net/xt_recent/BLOCKED")`.

Comment: You attached a bounty, and despite having an answer, didn't accept either/with no comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just write to file?

```
with open('/proc/net/xt_recent/BLOCKED', 'a') as f:
  f.write('+10.10.10.10')
```

Comment: To mimic the shame bash behavior you need to create/truncate the file not append.
And also append a newline at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You could do quite the same from Python:

```
with open('/proc/net/xt_recent/BLOCKED', 'w') as the_file:
  the_file.write('+10.10.10.10\n')
```

If you read [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/reading-writing-files-python) you'll see it's actually quite straightforward.

If you want to edit a file which requires permissions, run your python script as a super user.

`sudo python yourcode.py`

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the same on python.

```
with open('/proc/net/xt_recent/BLOCKED', 'w') as f:
  f.write('+10.10.10.10\n')
```